DocuSign ListStatusChangesOptions issue
When we filter using the 'from' date and 'to' date, we get no response. However, there are envelopes within these dates in the DocuSign account. How can we resolve this issue?
I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything, can anyone help me.
                var envelopesOptions = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions
                {
                    fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-Convert.ToInt32(days)).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
                };
                if (envelopesOptions.fromDate != "")
                {
                    EnvelopesInformation envelopesResponse = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, envelopesOptions);
                   
                    foreach (var envelope in envelopesResponse.Envelopes)
                    {
                        envelopeIds.Add(envelope.EnvelopeId);
                    }
                }


Please use Request Logging to see exactly what your app is sending to Docusign. Then update (edit) your question to include the body of the API request. You're  probably not sending what you think you are....
